# how not to make pointer to array[0] modifies array[0] at every cycle for

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

While I was trying to make 2 cycles that give a full array of maximum and minimum values by using arithmetic pointers, I found out that the value of `Arr[0]` modified its value at every iteration of `for`. I resolved this by saving the first value in another variable that I assigned again in `Arr[0]` while also resetting my pointer to the starting position.

Is there a way to code that prevent this from happening?

I tried to use all most common types of arithmetic of pointers and used `printf("\n array 0 = %d",Arr[0])` to show the values of `Arr[0]` at every interaction.

```
int main
{
    int count; int Arr[3]; //array is full of int values
    int *ptr=&Arr[0]; int *max=&Arr[0];
    ...
    for(count=0;count<10;count++)
    {
         if(*ptr>*max)
         {
             *max=*ptr;
         }
         ptr=ptr+1;
    }
    printf("%d",*max);
    ...
}
```

Comment: When you do `*max=*ptr`, you are modifying the value in the array.  If you are just wanting to adjust the pointer to point at the newly-found maximum value, you would need to `max=ptr`.

Comment: You also need to adjust your loop (currently 10 iterations) to match the number of entries in the array (which is 3 in your code)

Comment: Please post real code (read this: [mre]).

Comment: `int *ptr=&Arr[0]; int *max=&Arr[0];` is the same as `int *ptr=Arr; int *max=Arr;` [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

Comment: Thanks all for the answers.For what concern the expression guard i modified the length of the array  in the question and forgot to change it .Sorry for the format of the code it's my first time here and i'm not really used to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*max=*ptr;
```

you mean

```
max=ptr;
```

You don't put `*` blindly in front of every use of pointer variables, but only when you want to follow them. When you want to change where the pointer is pointing, there is no `*`.

Also: `count<10` should be `count<3` to match the array declaration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it's clear now.Sorry about the wrong guard expression i made the array length shorter in  the question and didnt notice the error.